# I am using Azure Microsoft for text_to_text translation but it throwing error like provide valid credentials

Tags: python-3.x

```
Even i am passing valid credentials also it docent translate text to text in azure microsoft 

import os, requests, uuid, json


subscriptionKey = 'a5d3b930fcb64daba78e1366346ad0ab'

base_url = 'https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com'
path = '/transliterate?api-version=3.0'
params = '&language=ja&fromScript=jpan&toScript=latn'
constructed_url = base_url + path + params

headers = {
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey,
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'X-ClientTraceId': str(uuid.uuid4())
}


body = [{
    'text': 'こんにちは'
}]

request = requests.post(constructed_url, headers=headers, json=body)
response = request.json()

print(json.dumps(response, sort_keys=True, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

output:
    {
        "error": {
            "code": 401000,
            "message": "The request is not authorized because credentials are missing or invalid."
        }
    }

Comment: Same here. Did you found a solution for that?